# Trying to resume app but losing variable assignment - android

Tags: android, fragment, onresume

I am developing an android app that sends/receives data via Bluetooth.

I have an activity that has a connect button and a disconnect button in one fragment and a fragment that doesn't have a UI that contains all the Bluetooth methods.

When the connect button is pressed I call `fragment.bluetoothConnect()` to start the connection process. This process works fine, up until the user rotates the screen. When they rotate the screen then try to initiate a connection, a null pointer exception is thrown.

The variables that are throwing the null exceptions are the three that are assigned to during the `onResume()` method in the bluetooth fragment. I have tried moving them to `onCreate()` and `onAttach()` but with no success.

In the bluetooth fragments onResume method i have the following lines of code:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   appContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext(); //Get the activity context
   btDeviceArray = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>(); 
   btDeviceNames = new ArrayList<String>();
   if (appContext == null)
      Log.d(BTTAG,"appContext is null ");
   else
      Log.d(BTTAG,"appContext is not null");
   }
```

When the screen is rotated Logcat prints the line "`appContext is not nul`l" meaning appContext has been assigned, however in another method I try the same test and I get "appContext is null"

Comment: try using "this" as context. see if its working...

Comment: remove `.getApplicationContext()` after `getActivity()`.

Comment: I have tried both methods without success. I cannot change to "this" because then it isn't a context any more and I cannot register receivers and removing getApplicationContext() did not have any effect